# how to identify rows having duplicate values in fields/columns of the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

In a table, I want to find the rows where at least 2 fields (columns) are having duplicate "not null" value. A generic SQL solution will be preferable because it can be used in any DB. If not so, Oracle and SQL Server are my target DBs. As an example

```
ID    COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
1      11     11       11      44
2      11     22       33      44
3      11     null     33      33
4      11     null     null    44
```

should return the following rows

```
ID    COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
1      11     11       11      44
3      11     null     33      33
```

The first row has 3 fields with duplicate value of 11 and other row has col3 and col4 have duplicate value of 33

Answer (score 2):

The brute force method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where (col1 = col2 or col1 = col3 or col1 = col4 or
       col2 = col3 or col2 = col4 or col3 = col4
      ) or
      (col1 is null and (col2 is null or col3 is null or col4 is null) or
       col2 is null and (col3 is null or col4 is null) or
       col3 is null and col4 is null
      )
```

This will work in any database.

Comment: brute force will not be a choice as I have around 15 odd columns in the table. It will be a brittle solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Oracle using `UNPIVOT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f89be/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ) As
SELECT 1,      11,     11,       11,      44 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,      11,     22,       33,      44 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,      11,     null,     33,      33 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,      11,     null,     null,    44 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT ( value FOR key IN ( COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ) )
  GROUP BY id, value
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT key ) > 1
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f89be/9/0)**:

```
| ID | COL1 |   COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
|----|------|--------|------|------|
|  1 |   11 |     11 |   11 |   44 |
|  3 |   11 | (null) |   33 |   33 |
```

If you want to match on `NULL` then just use `UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS`.

And SQL Server, with almost the same code (just need an alias on the `UNPIVOT`):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6695/3)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT ( value FOR name IN ( COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ) ) AS u
  GROUP BY id, value
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT name ) > 1
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6695/3/0)**:

```
| ID | COL1 |   COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
|----|------|--------|------|------|
|  1 |   11 |     11 |   11 |   44 |
|  3 |   11 | (null) |   33 |   33 |
```

**Update**:

You can also generate a brute force query using the `*_TAB_COLUMN` dictionary table in Oracle (there is probably an equivalent in SQL server):

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ('
       || LISTAGG(
            '"' || PRIOR COLUMN_NAME || '" = "' || COLUMN_NAME || '"',
            ' OR '
          ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
          || ')' AS query
FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
AND    COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'COL%'
AND    LEVEL = 2
START WITH COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'COL%'
CONNECT BY PRIOR COLUMN_ID < COLUMN_ID;
```

Which outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ("COL1" = "COL2" OR "COL1" = "COL3" OR "COL1" = "COL4" OR "COL2" = "COL3" OR "COL2" = "COL4" OR "COL3" = "COL4")
```

Comment: @MTO, this is interesting. Any input on performance as I need this query on a table with 15+ columns to check for duplicate with million+ rows. The solution seems to be natural and I will be trying during lean hours and update

Comment: @kishore The most performant query will be just to enumerate all permutations of pairs and compare them. I've added a query to automatically generate a brute force query enumerating all the permutations of pairs (which saves you having to code it by hand and making mistakes). The `UNPIVOT` queries are easy to write and maintain but need to do a lot more work to unpivot, aggregate and then get the full rows so will be much less performant (although whether it is still sufficiently performant is something you will need to test with your hardware, table, indexes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Solution without hardcoded column names(Sql Server). 
Lets say, our table is [#test]. Then our query is:

```
;with [temp] as (
    select
         [id]           =   id
        ,[col_name1]    =   [c1].[value]('local-name(.)',   'nvarchar(256)')
        ,[col_value1]   =   [c1].[value]('.',               'nvarchar(256)')
        ,[col_name2]    =   [c2].[value]('local-name(.)',   'nvarchar(256)')
        ,[col_value2]   =   [c2].[value]('.',               'nvarchar(256)')    
    from 
        [#test] as  [t]
    cross apply
        (
            select [data] = convert(xml, (select [t].* for xml path('row') ))
        )       as  [x]
    cross apply
        [x].[data].[nodes]('row/*') as [t1]([c1])
    cross apply
        [x].[data].[nodes]('row/*') as [t2]([c2])
)
,[ids] as (
    select 
        [id]
    from 
        [temp]
    where
            ([col_name1]    <>  [col_name2] )
        and ([col_value1]   =   [col_value2])
    group by
         [id]
)
select 
    *
from
    [#test] as  [t]
inner join
    [ids]   as  [i]
on
        [t].[id] = [i].[id];
```

Full query can be found: https://pastebin.com/jUG5r41c

Comment: what kind of performance hit I may expect with a table of 15 odd columns to be checked and million+ rows. Why do we need xml path construct here? Can you please explain

Comment: XML is to avoid column name hardcodes. Unpivot does not solve this - as we need to hardcode column names. My approach is to script entire row as XML, because XML allows us to select table column name without hardcode (local-name). And then join this XML using cross apply to find-out columns, that are the same. Performance will be problem on huge tables (XML node function is resource costly). But, unpivot is heavy (maybe heavier) too. This is cost of non-hardcoded query.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, i would use `APPLY` operator to do this :

```
select * 
from (select *, (select COUNT(*) from (values (Col1), (Col2),.. (ColN))t(ids)) TotalCols,
                (select COUNT(distinct ids) from (values (Col1), (Col2),.. (ColN))t(ids)) DistinctCols
      from table t
    ) t
where TotalIds <> DistinctCols;
```